# Pandas: Access the nth element in a Series.str.split('/")

Tags: python, pandas

If I do: `Series.str.split("/")` on a Pandas Series that has names like "A/American black duck/Illinois/4119/2009", then I get back a Pandas Series that has a list like:

```
[A, American black duck, Illinois, 4119, 2009]
```

in each row.

The state name (Illinois, for example) is what I would like to assign as a new column in a separate DataFrame. Is there some way to do something like the following?

```
newdf['State'] = Series.str.split("/")[2]
```

(For the record, I've already tried that, but it returns an error.)

Comment: I think this is a dup of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504976/get-last-column-after-str-split-operation-on-column-in-pandas-dataframe]): Wes' answer for your situation would be `s.str.split("/").str[2]`, and is better than mine.

Comment: DSM is correct that would work, also this works also: `df.col.str.split('/')[0][2]` but I prefer DSM's

Comment: The technical reason is that what `split` returns is another pandas series, it will have a single row with index value `0` and an NDArray of values, this is why you get a `KeyError` doing `Series.str.split("/")[2]`, you may be confused by the IPython output which looks like it is a list but it is not. Calling the method `str` on `split` again allows you to access the individual values

Comment: Wonderful, I did remember seeing that other question, but I couldn't find the right keywords to search for it. Would you all recommend that I delete my question?

Comment: I think not, I will vote to close as duplicate and over time it should get enough votes and be linked to that question

Comment: Ditto here. Thanks guys!

Comment: @DSM Ooooh, we can insta-close duplicate questions now! Wes' solution is concise/quite surprising... (@ericmjl Duplicate questions redirect on google searches for non-logged in users, so you're helping other people find the correct search in the future! +1)