# Split pandas column and add last element to a new column

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have a pandas dataframe containing (besides other columns) full names:

```
 fullname
 martin master
 andreas test
```

I want to create a new column which splits the fullname column along the blank space and assigns the last element to a new column. The result should look like:

```
 fullname           lastname
 martin master      master
 andreas test       test
```

I thought it would work like this:

```
df['lastname'] = df['fullname'].str.split(' ')[-1]
```

However, I get a `KeyError: -1`

I use `[-1]`, that is the last element of the split group, in order to be sure that I get the real last name. In some cases (e.g. a name like *andreas martin master*), this helps to get the last name, that is, *master*.

So how can I do this?

Comment: you can do it in one shot: `df[['first_name','last_name']] = df['fullname'].str.split(' ', expand=True)`

Comment: Or better `df[['first_name','last_name']] = df['fullname'].str.split(expand=True)`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need another `str` to access the last splits for every row, what you did was essentially try to index the series using a non-existent label:

```
In [31]:

df['lastname'] = df['fullname'].str.split().str[-1]
df
Out[31]:
         fullname lastname
0   martin master   master
1    andreas test     test
```

Comment: Similar thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504976/get-last-column-after-str-split-operation-on-column-in-pandas-dataframe/44976922#comment109692323_44976922

Answer (score 4):

If need create 2 new columns, use [`str.rsplit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) with parameter `n=1`. If need only last column, [`EdChum`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38498755/2901002) solution is better:

```
print (df)
                fullname
0          martin master
1           andreas test
2  andreas martin master

df[['first_name','last_name']] = df['fullname'].str.rsplit(expand=True, n=1)
print (df)
                fullname      first_name last_name
0          martin master          martin    master
1           andreas test         andreas      test
2  andreas martin master  andreas martin    master
```