# remove words from table index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table index looks like that:

```
k__Bacteria;p__Spirochaetes
k__Bacteria;p__Acidobacteria
k__Bacteria;p__Actinobacteria
k__Bacteria;p__Armatimonadetes
...........
```

I want to delete every word that come before the "*" ('k_Bacteria;p*') So that I have only the words "Spirochaetes", "Actinobacteria" and so forth.

how can I do it?

TNX!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split pandas column and add last element to a new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38498718/split-pandas-column-and-add-last-element-to-a-new-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need working with index values use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and select last values by indexing `[-1]`:

```
print (df)
                                col
k__Bacteria;p__Spirochaetes       1
k__Bacteria;p__Acidobacteria      2
k__Bacteria;p__Actinobacteria     3
k__Bacteria;p__Armatimonadetes    4

df.index = df.index.str.split('_').str[-1]
print (df)
                 col
Spirochaetes       1
Acidobacteria      2
Actinobacteria     3
Armatimonadetes    4
```

If need working with column `col` use:

```
print (df)
                              col
0     k__Bacteria;p__Spirochaetes
1    k__Bacteria;p__Acidobacteria
2   k__Bacteria;p__Actinobacteria
3  k__Bacteria;p__Armatimonadetes

df.col = df.col.str.split('_').str[-1]
print (df)
0     Spirochaetes
1    Acidobacteria
2   Actinobacteria
3  Armatimonadetes
```