# Creating a new column with last 2 values after a str.split operation

Tags: python, pandas

I came across this extremely well explained similar question ([Get last "column" after .str.split() operation on column in pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504976/get-last-column-after-str-split-operation-on-column-in-pandas-dataframe)), and used some of the codes found. However, it's not the output that I would like.

```
raw_data = {
    'category': ['sweet beverage, cola,sugared', 'healthy,salty snacks', 'juice,beverage,sweet', 'fruit juice,beverage', 'appetizer,salty crackers'],
    'product_name': ['coca-cola', 'salted pistachios', 'fruit juice', 'lemon tea', 'roasted peanuts']}                                                      
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
```

Objective is to extract the various categories from each row, and only use the last 2 categories to create a new column. I have this code, which works and I have the categories of interest as a new column.

```
df['my_col'] = df.categories.apply(lambda s:s.split(',')[-2:])

output
my_col 
[cola,sugared]
[healthy,salty snacks]
[beverage,sweet]
...
```

However, it appears as a list. How can I not have it appear as a list? Can this be achieved? Thanks all!!!!!

Comment: What then, if not a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html), select last to lists and last [`str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
df['my_col'] = df.category.str.split(',').str[-2:].str.join(',')
print (df)
                       category       product_name                    my_col
0  sweet beverage, cola,sugared          coca-cola              cola,sugared
1          healthy,salty snacks  salted pistachios      healthy,salty snacks
2          juice,beverage,sweet        fruit juice            beverage,sweet
3          fruit juice,beverage          lemon tea      fruit juice,beverage
4      appetizer,salty crackers    roasted peanuts  appetizer,salty crackers
```

EDIT:

In my opinion pandas `str` [text functions](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html) are more recommended as `apply` with puru python string functions, because also working with `NaN`s and `None`.

```
raw_data = {
    'category': [np.nan, 'healthy,salty snacks'],
    'product_name': ['coca-cola', 'salted pistachios']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)

df['my_col'] = df.category.str.split(',').str[-2:].str.join(',')
print (df)
               category       product_name                my_col
0                   NaN          coca-cola                   NaN
1  healthy,salty snacks  salted pistachios  healthy,salty snacks

df['my_col'] = df.category.apply(lambda s: ','.join(s.split(',')[-2:]))
```

> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Delivering as always!

Comment: Thanks @Jezrael for showing me these 2 methods. As a newbie, I would like not only achieve the desired results, but also learn why one method is chosen over the other.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `join` in the `lambda` to the result of `split`:

```
df['my_col'] = df.category.apply(lambda s: ','.join(s.split(',')[-2:]))
df
```

Result:

```
                       category       product_name                    my_col
0  sweet beverage, cola,sugared          coca-cola              cola,sugared
1          healthy,salty snacks  salted pistachios      healthy,salty snacks
2          juice,beverage,sweet        fruit juice            beverage,sweet
3          fruit juice,beverage          lemon tea      fruit juice,beverage
4      appetizer,salty crackers    roasted peanuts  appetizer,salty crackers
```