# Unpack a dictionary of pandas data frames (1,1)

Tags: python, pandas

my dictionary has tuples of (item, field) as keys and (1,1) dataframes as values with columns equal tuples (item, field), row index as a single date (same for all items), for example:

```
Key
('AB US Equity', 'CHG_PCT_1D')
('AB US Equity', 'PX_LAST')
('IBM US Equity', 'CHG_PCT_1D')
('IBM US Equity', 'PX_LAST')

Value   
    ('AB US Equity', 'CHG_PCT_1D')
2/15/2019   0.5362

('AB US Equity', 'PX_LAST')
2/15/2019   30
```

here is the dic:

```
   In [100]: str(dic)
Out[100]: "{('IBM US Equity', 'PX_LAST'):             (IBM US Equity, PX_LAST)\n2019-02-15                    138.03, ('IBM US Equity', 'CHG_PCT_1D'):             (IBM US Equity, CHG_PCT_1D)\n2019-02-15                       1.1357, ('AB US Equity', 'PX_LAST'):             (AB US Equity, PX_LAST)\n2019-02-15                     30.0, ('AB US Equity', 'CHG_PCT_1D'):             (AB US Equity, CHG_PCT_1D)\n2019-02-15                      0.5362}"
```

the below code puts them horizontally:

```
 output=pandas.concat(dic.values(),axis=1)
 output.columns=pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples(output.columns)
 output.columns.names=['Item','Field']
```

while having hundreds of items and a few fields I'd like to unpack it in the following vertical flat df:

```
   Value    CHG_PCT_1D  PX_LAST
AB US Equity    0.5362  30
IBM US Equity   1.1357  138.03
```

**SOLUTION**
(mainly based on the answer below)

```
import pandas as pd

dic = {('IBM US Equity', 'PX_LAST'): '2019-02-15    138.03',
 ('IBM US Equity', 'CHG_PCT_1D'):           
 '2019-02-15                       1.1357',
 ('AB US Equity', 'PX_LAST'):             
 '2019-02-15                     30.0',
 ('AB US Equity', 'CHG_PCT_1D'):
 '2019-02-15                      0.5362'}

output = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dic, orient = 'index')
# to series removing date
output = output[0].str.split().str[-1]
# unstack help, first example
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(output.index)
output = pd.Series(output.values, index=index).unstack()
```

Comment: can you write something to reconstruct what the input data dictionary looks like in Python code? Struggling to understand fully from the question

Comment: @SvenHarris  i updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). These will help you gather helpful responses more quickly.

IIUC, you are looking to [unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) the innermost level of the MultiIndex. Here is the code I reproduced from your question:

```
dic = {('IBM US Equity', 'PX_LAST'): '2019-02-15                    138.03',
 ('IBM US Equity', 'CHG_PCT_1D'):           
 '2019-02-15                       1.1357',
 ('AB US Equity', 'PX_LAST'):             
 '2019-02-15                     30.0',
 ('AB US Equity', 'CHG_PCT_1D'):
 '2019-02-15                      0.5362'}

output = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dic, orient = 'index')
output = output.reset_index()
output['a'] = output.apply(lambda row: row['index'][0], axis = 1)
output['b'] = output.apply(lambda row: row['index'][1], axis = 1)
output = output.drop(['index'], axis = 1)
output = output.groupby(['a', 'b']).sum().unstack()
output = output[0]
output['CHG_PCT_1D'] = output['CHG_PCT_1D'].str.split().str[-1]
output['PX_LAST'] = output['PX_LAST'].str.split().str[-1]
```

So when you run `output.to_string()`, you get:

```
b             CHG_PCT_1D PX_LAST
a                               
AB US Equity      0.5362    30.0
IBM US Equity     1.1357  138.03
```

Based on your question, I have no clue what you want the different columns or indices to be named. I also don't know what type of aggregate function to run on the grouped dataframe.

Comment: Apologies,  wanted output.columns = ['CHG_PCT_1D', 'PX_LAST'] and drop the date completely from the output.

Comment: I've updated my code to address your comment. The solution is based on code found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13053267/1301888