# vaex extract one column of str.split()

Tags: python, vaex

I want nearly the same as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13053267) for `pandas` - but want to run it in `vaex`.
As `vaex` does lazy copy, for me it would be okay, to save (my two) columns of `str.split` into the vaex-df. But there is nothing like `expand=True`.

Answer (score 1):

To do this with vaex 4.0.0 you can't retrieve a token by using the slice directly, you have to use the slice inside the `apply` method.

Here is the example adapted for vaex:

```py
import pandas as pd
import vaex

df = pd.DataFrame({'ticker' : ['spx 5/25/2001 p500', 'spx 5/25/2001 p600', 'spx 5/25/2001 p700']})

df_vaex = vaex.from_pandas(df)

df_vaex["ticker"].str.split(" ").apply(lambda x: x[-1])
```

And it gives the expected output:

```py
Expression = lambda_function(str_split(ticker, ' '))
Length: 3 dtype: string (expression)
------------------------------------
0  p500
1  p600
2  p700
```