# str.split not working, but no errors generated

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe, csv, concatenation

I have a dataframe with address data, but some data is in the wrong column and they need to get shifted so the first field is always the first row of the address.

A somewhat simplified version of the dataframe looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

addresses = {'add1': ['1', '54', '12-18', ' '], 'add2': ['moore street', 'fountain road', 'st margaret house', '15']}

df = pd.DataFrame(addresses)
```

To solve this, I created another column (a1,a2) that concatenates the values from add1 and add2 with a column, and a few other lines to strip out extraneous commas and double commas, with the aim of then using this to split the data out again using `str.split()` and the commas as delimiters.

```
df['a1,a2'] = df['add1'].astype(str) + ',' + df['add2'].astype(str) + ','

df['a1,a2'] = df['a1,a2'].str.lstrip(',')

df.replace(',,', ',', regex=True, inplace=True)

df['a1,a2'] = df['a1,a2'].str.rstrip(',')
df['a1,a2'] = df['a1,a2'].str.rstrip('"')
df['a1,a2'] = df['a1,a2'].str.lstrip('"')
```

So far so good. When I export this to a csv file and then split out the columns in Excel I get the right result.

So then I add row to split them out in the dataframe, into new columns

```
df['a1,a2'].str.split(',', expand=True)
```

This runs fine, and I get no errors but the resultant file still has the new column as one, not split across new columns.

When I open the csv output in notepad I can see that the new column 'a1,a2' is enclosed in quote marks ("a1,a2") and the same for the data rows

I assume that when the columns are concatenated it makes a single list (?) and so ignores the delimiters within it, but I cannot figure out how to get it to be a normal string so it will split.

Comment: 1) `df['a1,a2'].str.split(', ')` is split by `, ` (tailing space), but your `a1,a2` column doesn't have `, `(comma space). 2) `df['a1,a2'].str.split(', ')` is not inplace, you need assign the result to new column.

Comment: Sorry, that's just a typo when I wrote it out here. There isn't a trailing space in the proper version.

As I understand it, the expand=True ought to pull them out to new columns?

Answer (score 1):

OK, thanks to the clue from [Ynjxsjmh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10315163/ynjxsjmh) I managed to work it out (or rather, google the right thing).

The split columns are now a new dataframe and I renamed the source column so that it was easier to reference

```
expanded = df.concat.str.split(',', expand=True)
```

then renamed the columns

```
expanded = expanded.rename(columns={0: 'add1', 1:'add2'})
```

and added them back into the source dataframe, then dropped the original address columns and exported to csv to check the data.

A bit more info [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504976/get-last-column-after-str-split-operation-on-column-in-pandas-dataframe?rq=1)